# Better Sliding Window, Feature Extraction

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-recognition, digits, inference

I am currently trying to implement a digit recognizer on a video stream. Which is able to scan handwritten digits on objects, these digits represent an inventory number. The digits are written on a homogenous background, so there are no hard contrast changes, except for the regions with digits.

First I implemented the classical sliding window approach, then I recognized this is to slow for Realtime. Then I tried to calculate a spatial C-dimensional (C=classes) map of  the image, following the approach of “Overfeat”, described in the following paper: Link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6229

Now I ask myself, weather this is the right approach to solve this problem, is there maybe a solution, where I crop all image areas where big contrast changes are happening, because obviously written numbers would be contained in this region?

Thank you in advance for your help and time.